# How to put only True values on the plotly bargraph axis python

Tags: python, boolean, plotly

My data looks like this

| A | B | c | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| string1 | False | 3 | False |
| string2 | True | 3 | False |
| string3 | True | 2 | True |

How do I show only True value count on a plotly  bar graph?

I tried this:

```
fig = px.histogram(df, x=["B", "D])
```

It shows both True and False , I only want to display the True values

Comment: @SylvesterKruin It shows both True and False , I only want to display the True value count

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the true values in the xaxis you can modify the contents of **x** to only include **True**

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""A,B,c,D
string1,False,3,False
string2,True,3,False
string3,True,2,True"""))

px.histogram(df, x=["B", "D"]).for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(x=[b for b in t.x if b]))
```